# What's the proper way to edit the text and the links of a menubar in a php file?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to change the text of an element in my menubar depending on the user action. If the user logged in, the tab is marked 'My space' else it's marked 'Connection'.

So I had the idea to transmit a variable from the login.php file (the page where we log in) to my home.php file. So for example, when the user log in, I set a variable

```
$connected=true
```

in login.php.

My problem is that when I use

```
include 'login.php';
```

to get the $connected variable in the home.php file, I get all the content of login.php, including html contents that I don't want.

So what's the common method to actualize a menubar ? Transmit variables with include ? Use javascript ? Save a variable in a separate file ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have some sort of logic that determines if `$connection=true;`

Traditionally you would put this into a function because that would allow you to call a specific piece of code anywhere in your code.

Here is a rough example:

```
function isUserLoggedIn() {
    $connected = false;

    // logic to check if user is logged in
    if ($_SESSION['connected'] === true) {
        $connected = true;
    }
    return $connected;
}

// How to use
$connected = isUserLoggedIn();
```

Then use this anywhere in your code.

Create a functions.php file and include that, like this you won't have mixed content, it will be separate.